# Windows 10 explorer not refreshing

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Windows Explorer will not auto-refresh and show a new folder that is created (until Ctrl-R is pressed), nor will it remove a file from view that is deleted (until Ctrl-R is pressed).

How can I get Windows Explorer to begin auto-refreshing again?

I would also notice other programs that opened or created files to hang during creation/opening.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I attempted the registry key fix:

Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance` (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance` for 64-bit systems) and create a DWORD (for 32-bit systems) or QWORD (64-bit systems) labeled `dontrefresh` with a value of `0`.

...and while it may work for some people, it did not work for me.

I tried the following:

- In Windows Explorer: choose Tools, Folder Options > Click the Search tab

  > Check or uncheck ANY option
- Apply.
- If this solves your problem, you can revert to your original setting and the
  problem will remain solved.

...and while it may work for some people, it did not work for me.

I ran `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth&sfc /scannow&pause` in an administrator Command Prompt and it found no issues (though it may work for you).

**Solving my issue:**

I found that a Samba file share that I had pinned to Quick Access was causing my issue. When the Samba file share was not present, Windows Explorer would freak out. After deleting the file share from my pinned Quick Access, the problem disappeared.

Comment: This was my problem, too. It wasn't a Samba folder but a network share that is only accessible when I'm connected to my corporate VPN. I deleted that share and things started working normally again.

Comment: "Quick Access shortcut to network share" was my problem, too. Thank you very much.

Comment: This was the problem here too... In my case, after deleting conflictive folders, I had to kill the "explorer.exe" process from the task manager and execute it again in order to make it work properly.

Comment: The first one worked for me. I had to create the `{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}` key, and also the `Instance` key under it.

Comment: I just want to add something that not everyone might be aware of: My problem too was solved by removed a pinned share ... but that share was a directory in my WSL installation - which obviously is also accessed via network, even though it is on your machine.

Comment: Like you and Tommy, I think my issue, at least today, may have been a network share. I have a drive (Partition) in my gaming desktop that I use as a budget alternative to NAS so I can map it and have the same folders on my laptop. Today, however, I was roaming for the holiday, and thus was on a different network. I have hamachi (temporarily while I figure out how the heck to set wireguard up. All the guides I find seem to be for Linux), but that doesn't do me a lot of good when I'm on mobile hotspot and hit a dead zone.

Comment: '{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}' didn't exist on Windows 10 22H2, had to create it as @Addison said, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

Try This:
1.  Right click on desktop.
2.  Select personalize
3.  Click on themes
4.  Scroll down and click on desktop icon settings
5.  Click restore default
6.  Click ok

Comment: This worked for me in July 2020 when no other fix would.

Comment: I tried everything else, but this finally solved it for me

Comment: Wow man, such an unrelated action fixes this, I would have never thought...

Answer (score -1):

Looking at explorer, and right clicking on the column header, I needed to change from date, to date modified.  It appears the default is the creation date.

Comment: Hey Dan! Thanks for joining. What was the objective with your answer? It appears to be irrelevant to the question being asked.

Answer (score -1):

This was driving me nuts!  I create a new folder or link on the desktop and it doesn't show until I force a Refresh.

I solved it this way:

Open Explorer and click once on your C: drive (any folder should work)

In the menu bar, go to the VIEW tab, then options, then open search and folder options.

Then under the General tab only, restore defaults.  As well, change the dropdown at the top from "Quick Access" to "This PC" ... then save and done.   Play with those settings because this has something to do with Quick access.

I hope this helps someone.

Danny B (aka; Gern)